# Why Cloud texture has square cell pattern?

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine

When I am using Cloud texture as bump map in Blender Render, this cells appear. How can I make them go away?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might consider settings like this.

[image]

Influence [Color] and No influence [Normal]

It is not clear that the User can use all clouds as a Normal Map.  Normal Map and Bump Map are different.

Any one can paint a bump map manually.  That is not true of Normal map.
Normal Maps can baked.

You may also want to see the Displacement Modifier which uses textures.

Short answer, rather than a complete technical answer.